# MySQL use WHERE clause to get most recent item that has a particular column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some form data that's been stored into my database. I want to output the data from the table. However, I only want to output the most recent one if the column "is_featured" is set to 1. So I need to know how to use the WHERE clause and grab the most recent item if the column "is_featured" is set to 1. Here's my code so far but it doesn't work.

Also uploaded is a screenshot of my database table with the data inside. [image]

```
$itemAddedInfoById = "SELECT product_name, product_price, product_descr, product_img, is_raffle, is_featured, raffle_category FROM upload_items WHERE is_featured = 1; ";
```

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to add a date/datetime column and query on the date/time.

Comment: Your `WHERE` is fine. But if you only want the most recent, then you're going need to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

Comment: You should create another field --  I usually create two -- `date_added` and `date_modified`  -- Set them as `TIMESTAMP` and set the default on `date_added` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` -- And set the default on `date_modified` to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @aynber When I had it as a WHERE an ORDER BY, I got an error message. This wad my original code >    $itemAddedInfoById = "SELECT product_name, product_price, product_descr, product_img, is_raffle, is_featured, raffle_category FROM upload_items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; WHERE is_featured = 1; ";

Comment: @Zak are you saying when I add this field I should get the data based on the time it was updated?

Comment: @Aishah91 exactly .. Read my answer for full description

Answer (score 2):

The **CORRECT** way to do this is:

You should create another field in the database

I usually create two:

```
date_added 
date_modified
```

Set them as `TIMESTAMP` and set the default on `date_added` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` -- And set the default on `date_modified` to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

IE

```
ALTER TABLE `your_database`.`your_table` 
ADD COLUMN `date_added` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `raffle_category`,
ADD COLUMN `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `date_added`;
```

Then you will have a column with the date the item was inserted .. And a column that will let you know when they were updated.  Then you can simply:

```
ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 1
```

to grab the most current entered row.  Change `LIMIT` to grab the last `X`

Your Query:

```
$itemAddedInfoById = "SELECT product_name,
                             product_price,
                             product_descr,
                             product_img,
                             is_raffle,
                             is_featured,
                             raffle_category 
              FROM upload_items 
              WHERE is_featured = 1
              ORDER BY date_added DESC
              LIMIT 1; ";
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, feel free to mark it as "accepted" so others know this solved the issue ..